# Swift Compiler Error: use of undeclared type with framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-errors, frameworks

I'm importing a newer version of a custom framework LCCommLibrary that creates the `LCConnection` class and I'm absolutely perplexed why this will build but not archive after trying multiple things.

- Making sure the targets are added (4 apps, 1 Test)
- Cleaning and Restarting the Project

This does builds and runs to my iOS devices, but none of the targets will Archive.

[image: Build Phases]

[image: Compiler Error]

Comment: Could you try to deselect `Copy when installing` and see if makes any difference? Also, remove the library from the Embedded Frameworks and only leave it in the `Link Binary with Libraries` section

Comment: Thanks for the reply @CatalinaT. I tried both methods but was not able to archive.

Comment: I'm not sure this should matter but have you tried archiving with a Generic iOS Device rather than your actual device? The latter is not recommended.

Comment: @allocate I have. That said, I tried it again.

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried the semi-obvious stuff like deleting derived data and/or possibly re-cloning?

Comment: @allocate - yep. I'm starting to think there's something wrong with the framework.

Comment: Yeah, I can't think of a legit reason why you should be fine building to the device but not archiving in this instance -- especially since you don't seem to be using any kind of dependency management.

Comment: Have you attempted to remove the test target and then use @testable import from your tests to bring in the project? It is possible that there is some other piece of LCConnection that is not exposed to test, so the compiler is complaining about that.

Comment: @Macness An archive build is different from a development build. Check your Release settings, as well as making sure the framework is actually compiled with the proper binaries. Can you build the framework in the project directly? Just add the .xcodeproj file instead of the framework itself and see if it helps

Comment: Hey if possible can you check in your code to an online repository like github. That way it would be easier for the people trying to answer this question.

Comment: @Macness I faced same issue but when I try to import framework in every class where I need that framework and same import in BridgingHeader.h,Issue solved for me.

Comment: @CodeBender yes I have tried messing around with the tests in general.

Comment: @AntwanvanHoudt I think this is the likely problem as when I change the archive scheme to debug, I get different results.

Comment: @Md.IbrahimHassan Sorry I can't publish this code publicly :(

Comment: @VDPurohit I have checked and rechecked the Bridging header part. I'm thinking that I will create a new target and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the issue.  The culprit was framework that was included was a `debug` version of the framework. This causes `Archive Schemes` to throw this error since the archive uses the `Release` as the default.

The resolution was to open the `LCCommLibrary` Project separately, change the Framework Target's Run Scheme to `Release`, Run and Build, Locate the target framework, import and embed that back into main project file, and archive as usual.

Answer (score 2):

Archive usually uses the `Release` build configuration while building/running on the device uses the `Debug` build configuration, this is the hint that you have an issue there.

I would say in your case you can to go into the target's build settings, then look at `Other Linker Flags`, `Runpath Search Paths` and `Library Search Paths`, expand them to show the `Debug` and `Release` configurations and then ensure you have the same settings for both of them, you'll most probably find something missing in `release` in one of those.

Comment: This is true in most scenarios, but of course I have scoured those build settings more than I care to admit! I upvoted this comment as it is useful. I found the issue was a debug version of the framework was used.